# Heightmap from contour lines with SciPy griddata

Tags: python, scipy, gis, interpolation

I have a topographic map with height contour lines and want to generate a heightmap from it(grid with each cell having height as value) with scipy.interpolate.griddata. My idea is to add points of the contour lines as unstructured datapoints to the interpolation algorithm and ask interpolated values(heights) for the whole grid.

For some reason, griddata() returns a grid that mostly is not interpolated between two contour lines and grid points between two contour lines get low values, not values between the two contour line values.

Below is my example 20x20 image with contour lines (left) and the resulting interpolated grid (1000x1000). Only non-zero values(non-black pixels) from the contour lines are used as input to the interpolation. The same problem persists with 'nearest', 'linear' and 'cubic' interpolation method. Any ideas why can't I get the heighmap I am expecting?
[image: Image of contour lines and interpolation result]

Source code can be [found here - http://pastebin.com/umNmSrE2](http://pastebin.com/umNmSrE2)

**Update:** Problem solved. Actually bad input image was the problem (see comment below). The new result is:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the `if contours[row,col][0] != 0:` in your source code is really bypassing all the points not on a contour line? What is `len(contourPoints)` after you process your `.bmp` file? That´s the only explanation I can think of for waht you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, Jamie, for the suggestions. The problem is solved. I did not notice, that GIMP has given some of the black pixels low non-zero values like 1, 2, 3. So there were low-value data points that I did not know about and they gave the initial result. The new result is here [http://snag.gy/9JKmw.jpg](http://snag.gy/9JKmw.jpg)